# Simple Logical Error in Python

Tags: python, function, csv, functional-programming

Lines 12 and 13 of my code are not affecting the program.

Current output:

hi     10

hi     10

hola   10

Desired output:

hi     10

hi     6

hola   10

The second number in the right column of the CSV output should be changed to 6, not 10 (due to lines 12 and 13) Why are these lines not having an affect?

Thanks for any help or ideas.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
levels = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"]]
def column1Logic(self, level, greeting):
    self.column1 = "logic worked"
    if greeting == ["hola"]:
        self.column1 = ["poop"]
    else:
        self.column1 = self.greeting
def column2Logic(self, level, greeting): # budget
    self.column2 = 10 
    if level == [2]: 
        self.column2 = self.column2 * .6
class Row(object):
    column1 = "name"
    column2 = "budget"
    greeting = "oh"
    def __init__(self, level, greeting):
        self.level = level
        self.greeting = greeting
    def rowEntry(self, level, greeting):
        column1Logic(self, level, greeting)
        column2Logic(self, level, greeting)
        lol = [[self.column1], [self.column2]]
        lol[0] = self.column1
        lol[1] = self.column2
        file_writer.writerow([o for o in lol])
with open("test.csv", "wb") as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for a in range(0, len(levels)):
        if levels[a] == ["3"]:
            greeting = "hola"
            food = Row(levels[a], greeting)
            food.rowEntry(levels[a], greeting)
        else:
            greeting = "hi"
            food = Row(levels[a], greeting)
            food.rowEntry(levels[a], greeting)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if level == [2]:` needs to use the string `'2'` rather than the number `2` for that condition to ever evaluate to `True`. You got it right with `if levels[a] == ["3"]:` in a different line.

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel dumb!

Comment: You got it right elsewhere in the program - everyone makes this sort of mistake occasionally.